# I have a UK tourist visa. Can I apply for a NiN as an EEA family member?

Tags: united-kingdom, uk-visa, family

I'm married to a Spanish national in Ireland, where I have the Treaty Rights card. I've recently got a UK tourist visa, which is still valid for 4 months.

Since we are planning to move to the UK next year (January/February), I'm wondering if I could still apply for the NiN while in the UK on my tourist visa or do I absolutely need the EEA family permit visa prior to that?

Comment: You don't need the EEA family permit for much of anything, but I think you do need to be resident in the UK before you can apply for the NIN.  So if you apply during a visit you should be refused.  (If you're going to the UK with your spouse and your residence card, you also don't need a tourist visa.)